# Masstransit scheduler with quartz.net object reference not set while reading message

Tags: masstransit, quartz.net

I've been receiving the following error while setting up the quartz.net scheduler with MassTransit

After the message is scheduled on the RabbitMQ, when the quartz.net tries to read it, the error is thrown:

```
MT-Fault-Message:   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
MT-Fault-Timestamp: 2021-06-02T18:46:56.1335404Z
MT-Fault-StackTrace:    at MassTransit.QuartzIntegration.ScheduleMessageConsumer.TranslateJsonBody(String body, String destination)
at MassTransit.QuartzIntegration.ScheduleMessageConsumer.CreateJobDetail(ConsumeContext context, Uri destination, JobKey jobKey, Nullable`1 tokenId)
at MassTransit.QuartzIntegration.ScheduleMessageConsumer.Consume(ConsumeContext`1 context)
at MassTransit.Pipeline.ConsumerFactories.DelegateConsumerFactory`1.Send[TMessage](ConsumeContext`1 context, IPipe`1 next)
at MassTransit.Pipeline.ConsumerFactories.DelegateConsumerFactory`1.Send[TMessage](ConsumeContext`1 context, IPipe`1 next)
at MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.ConsumerMessageFilter`2.GreenPipes.IFilter<MassTransit.ConsumeContext<TMessage>>.Send(ConsumeContext`1 context, IPipe`1 next)
at MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.ConsumerMessageFilter`2.GreenPipes.IFilter<MassTransit.ConsumeContext<TMessage>>.Send(ConsumeContext`1 context, IPipe`1 next)
at GreenPipes.Partitioning.Partition.Send[T](T context, IPipe`1 next)
at GreenPipes.Filters.TeeFilter`1.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<<Send>g__SendAsync|1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at GreenPipes.Filters.OutputPipeFilter`2.SendToOutput(IPipe`1 next, TOutput pipeContext)
at GreenPipes.Filters.OutputPipeFilter`2.SendToOutput(IPipe`1 next, TOutput pipeContext)
at GreenPipes.Filters.DynamicFilter`1.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<<Send>g__SendAsync|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.DeserializeFilter.Send(ReceiveContext context, IPipe`1 next)
at GreenPipes.Filters.RescueFilter`2.GreenPipes.IFilter<TContext>.Send(TContext context, IPipe`1 next)
MT-Fault-ConsumerType:  MassTransit.QuartzIntegration.ScheduleMessageConsumer
MT-Fault-MessageType:   MassTransit.Scheduling.ScheduleMessage
```

This is how the ConfigureServices is setup:

```
.ConfigureServices((host, services) =>
                {
                    services.Configure<OtherOptions>(host.Configuration);
                    services.Configure<QuartzOptions>(host.Configuration.GetSection("Quartz"));

                    services.AddSingleton<QuartzConfiguration>();

                    services.AddMassTransit(x =>
                    {
                        x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
                        {
                            var options = context.GetService<QuartzConfiguration>();

                            cfg.AddScheduling(s =>
                            {
                                s.SchedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory(options.Configuration);
                                s.QueueName = options.Queue;
                            });

                            var vhost = host.Configuration.GetValue<string>("RabbitMQ:VirtualHost");

                            cfg.Host(string.Empty, vhost, h =>
                            {
                                h.Username( host.Configuration.GetValue<string>("RabbitMQ:User"));
                                h.Password(host.Configuration.GetValue<string>("RabbitMQ:Password"));
                                h.UseCluster(c =>
                                {
                                    c.Node(host.Configuration.GetValue<string>("RabbitMQ:Node1"));
                                    c.Node(host.Configuration.GetValue<string>("RabbitMQ:Node2"));
                                });
                            });

                        });
                    });

                    services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
                });
```

And this is how the quartz configs are setup:

```
public NameValueCollection Configuration
        {
            get
            {
                var configuration = new NameValueCollection(13)
                {
                    {"quartz.scheduler.instanceName", _options.Value.InstanceName},
                    {"quartz.scheduler.instanceId", "AUTO"},
                    {"quartz.plugin.timeZoneConverter.type","Quartz.Plugin.TimeZoneConverter.TimeZoneConverterPlugin, Quartz.Plugins.TimeZoneConverter"},
                    {"quartz.serializer.type", "json"},
                    {"quartz.threadPool.type", "Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz"},
                    {"quartz.threadPool.threadCount", (_options.Value.ThreadCount ?? 10).ToString("F0")},
                    {"quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold", "60000"},
                    {"quartz.jobStore.type", "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz"},
                    {"quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType", "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SqlServerDelegate, Quartz"},
                    {"quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix", _options.Value.TablePrefix},
                    {"quartz.jobStore.dataSource", "default"},
                    {"quartz.dataSource.default.provider", _options.Value.Provider},
                    {"quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString", _options.Value.ConnectionString},
                    {"quartz.jobStore.useProperties", "true"}
                };

                foreach (var key in configuration.AllKeys)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("{Key} = {Value}", key, configuration[key]);
                }

                return configuration;
            }
        }
```

Also the extension method to setup MassTransit scheduling:

```
public static void AddScheduling(this IBusFactoryConfigurator configurator, Action<InMemorySchedulerOptions> configure)
        {
            if (configurator == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configurator));

            var options = new InMemorySchedulerOptions();
            configure?.Invoke(options);

            if (options.SchedulerFactory == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(options.SchedulerFactory));

            var observer = new SchedulerBusObserver(options);
            
            configurator.ReceiveEndpoint(options.QueueName, e =>
            {
                var partitioner = configurator.CreatePartitioner(Environment.ProcessorCount);

                e.Consumer(() => new ScheduleMessageConsumer(observer.Scheduler), x =>
                    x.Message<ScheduleMessage>(m => m.UsePartitioner(partitioner, p => p.Message.CorrelationId)));

                e.Consumer(() => new CancelScheduledMessageConsumer(observer.Scheduler), x =>
                    x.Message<CancelScheduledMessage>(m => m.UsePartitioner(partitioner, p => p.Message.TokenId)));

                configurator.UseMessageScheduler(e.InputAddress);

                configurator.ConnectBusObserver(observer);
            });
        }
```

I tried debugging and couldn't find a reason for the error I'm receiving, the database connections are being created successfully and also the message scheduling on the consumer is being completed successfully.
Is there a way to actually debug while the scheduler is reading the message or to know what's exactly missing that is throwing the Object reference error?

**EDIT**
Debugging the Masstransit.Quartz framework I noticed the issue is while trying to deserialize the message on method TranslateJsonBody.

```
var envelope = JObject.Parse(body);

envelope["destinationAddress"] = destination;

var message = envelope["message"];

var payload = message["payload"];

var payloadType = message["payloadType"];
```

As you can see, the method uses camelCase, and our broker is sending with PascalCase, and since there's no handler, it's returning null when the method tries to get `envelope["message"]` because we're sending it as "Message". Is there any configuration to force camelCase when deserializing?

Comment: You could set a breakpoint in that method, and see what's null in the TranslateJsonBody method.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson unfortunately that's not possible because this method is inside Masstransit.quartzintegration package

Comment: Well, if you create a standalone repository on GitHub that reproduces the problem, you can submit an issue. The code above isn't nearly enough to even think about it. The Quartz scheduler only works with JSON or XML messages, maybe that's your issue. Who knows, as I stated, not enough on the _usage_ side to know.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson I updated the post with some new informations, if you can read and try and provide some insights, it'd be helpful, thanks!

Comment: Are you not using MassTransit to schedule the message? If so, it seems like you're customizing the serializer settings and they aren't working with what the Quartz service expects.

Comment: Yes, I'm using MassTransit to schedule the message, to do that, I followed the following guide: https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/scheduling/